# To remove error message when user clicked on legend label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In my Laravel 5.7 app I use Chart.js 2.7.2 and in Stacked line chart Open modal  dialog when user clicks
on points of the report like:

```
    var lineCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasVotesByDays");
    var lineCanvasContext = lineCanvas.getContext('2d');
    $("#div_canvasVotesByDays").css("display", "block")

    var numberWithCommas = function (x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    };
    var self = this;

    if (window.chartLineObject != undefined) { // clear existing instance
        window.chartLineObject.destroy();
    }

    window.chartLineObject = new Chart(lineCanvasContext, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: monthsXCoordItems,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Correct Votes',
                    data: voteValuesCorrect,
                    borderWidth: 1,           // The stroke width of the line in pixels.
                },
                {
                    label: 'Incorrect Votes',
                    data: voteValuesNoneCorrect,
                    borderWidth: 1,           // The stroke width of the line in pixels.
                }
            ]
        },

        options: { // options of Report By Vote Days ( 'line' report )
            animation: {
                duration: 10,
            },

            tooltips: { // tooltip text of Report By Vote Days ( 'line' report )
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                    }
                }
            }, // tooltips: { // tooltip text of Report By Vote Days ( 'line' report )

            scales: { // options for x and y scales of 'line' report
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,    // Stacked line charts can be used to show how one data series i
                    gridLines: {display: true},
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,  // Stacked line charts can be used to show how one data series i
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function (value) {  // on Y scale show only integer without decimals
                            if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
                                return value;
                            }  // return numberWithCommas(value);
                        },
                    },
                }],
            }, // scales: { // options for x and y scales of 'line' report
            legend: {display: true}
        } // options: { // options of Report By Vote Days ( 'line' report )

    }); // window.chartLineObject = new Chart(lineCanvasContext, {

    lineCanvas.onclick = function (e) {
        var firstPoint = window.chartLineObject.getElementsAtEvent(e);
        if (typeof firstPoint[0] == "undefined") {
            popupAlert("Select one of visible dots to get detailed results !", 'danger')
            return;
        }
        if (firstPoint) {
            var first_point_index = firstPoint[0]._index
            if (typeof window.chartLineObject.data.labels[first_point_index] == "undefined") {
                popupAlert("Bad point !", 'danger')
                return;
            }

            var selected_day = window.chartLineObject.data.labels[first_point_index];
            backendReports.showVoteNamesReportDetailsByDays(selected_day)
            return;
        }
    } // window.chartLineObject.onclick = function(e) {
```

This function :

```
lineCanvas.onclick = function (e) {
    var firstPoint = window.chartLineObject.getElementsAtEvent(e);
    if (typeof firstPoint[0] == "undefined") {
        popupAlert("Select one of visible dots to get detailed results !", 'danger')
        return;
    }
```

I use as I need to open dialog model only when user clicks on visible dots of the report
It works ok, but the problem is that at top of the report there is legend block (it also works as filter)
and click on this legend items I got error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBAh.jpg

If there is a way to check that clicked area is legend label ?

You can see it live at http://votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/report_votes_by_days

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use chart onclick event and canvas onclick together. canvas onclick has filter function, chart onclick has show modal.

```
    onClick: function(c,i) {
            e = i[0];
            var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
            var y_value = this.data.datasets[0].data[e._index];
            var ID = x_value;
            var Tip =1;
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback,
1) But I do not see any filter applied in your code?
Could cyou please to give a linnk to such filter described?

2) id there is a difference when onclick of event and canvas onclick defined  together  ?